# Postgres ошибка при вызове таблицы из схемы

Tags: postgresql, консоль, psql

Имеется 2 базы данных допустим bd1 и bd2. При подключении к bd1 прекрасно работают запросы на вывод данных из таблицы tbl1 схемы shm2. Однако при подключении к bd2 начинаются ошибки из разряда "отношения не существуют". Видимо какая-то проблема с правами? Сделал владельца для bd2 такого же как для bd1, однако это не помогло.

```
 Список баз данных
Имя    | Владелец | Кодировка | LC_COLLATE  |  LC_CTYPE   |     Права доступа
bd2 | owner | UTF8      | ru_RU.UTF-8 | ru_RU.UTF-8 |
bd1 | owner | UTF8      | ru_RU.UTF-8 | ru_RU.UTF-8 |
```

Схема видна из bd1 при `\dt *.*`:

```
Список отношений
   Схема        |              Имя              |   Тип   | Владелец
shm3          | pbl_oper                      | таблица | owner
```

Однако при подключении к bd2 команда `\dt *.*` не показывает эту схему. Сам только начал разбираться с postgres потому не до конца понимаю некоторые вопросы.Как сделать так, что бы при подключении к bd2 я мог просматривать таблицы из схемы shm1?

Answer (score 0):

Команда `\dt .` в `psql` выполняет запрос вот такого вида (можно поглядеть, если запустить `psql -E`):

```
SELECT n.nspname as "Schema",
  c.relname as "Name",
  CASE c.relkind WHEN 'r' THEN 'table' WHEN 'v' THEN 'view' WHEN 'm' THEN 'materialized view' WHEN 'i' THEN 'index' WHEN 'S' THEN 'sequence' WHEN 's' THEN 'special' WHEN 'f' THEN 'foreign table' WHEN 'p' THEN 'table' END as "Type",
  pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(c.relowner) as "Owner"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
     LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE c.relkind IN ('r','p','s','')
      AND n.nspname !~ '^pg_toast'
  AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

И самая важная здесь деталь - вызов функции [`pg_table_is_visible`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html) которая проверяет, что схема таблицы упомянута в настройке `search_path`. То есть таблица доступна по имени в запросах без указания имени `namespace`. Но это не права доступа, только порядок поиска объектов если не указана схема явным образом. Соответственно если различаются результаты запроса, хотя схема базы должна быть такая же - значит различается `search_path`.

Посмотреть текущие значения `search_path` можно командой:

```
show search_path;
```

Задаваться может глобально, на пользователя от которого подключаетесь, на конкретную БД.

Все таблицы во всех схемах без проверки `search_path` можно посмотреть командой `\dt *.*`

Comment: Видимо тут не пропечаталось съело пару символов)
При запросе команды \dt * . *  из bd1  я вижу все таблицы(кроме тех которые в bd2), а из bd2 - нет. 
show search_path; в обоих случаях однаковый

Comment: Проверьте в `\dn` есть ли такая схема вообще

Comment: При подключении к bd1 и команде '\dn' вижу схему public и shm1, при подключении к bd2 и команде '\dn' вижу схему public и bd2

Comment: Ну соответственно нет такой схемы и значит таблиц в ней быть не может.

Comment: Тогда видимо стоит создать схему shm2 в нее поместить bd2? Возможно даже подскажите как?)

Comment: Если вы хотите переименовать схему - то `alter schema (current_name) rename to (new_name)`

Comment: Я хочу что бы из bd2 можно было видеть shm1

Comment: Ну так создайте эту схему. Или в смысле из bd2 обращаться запросами к таблице в схеме расположенной в bd1?

Comment: Да обращаться из bd2 к схеме в bd1

Comment: Так это совершенно другой вопрос =( Обращения к другой базе не реализованы. Используйте dblink или FDW вместо этого.